# Wordpress get custom post count

Tags: wordpress

I need custom query for showing posts count outside of loop.

Results need be filter by:

```
Taxanomy = ad_cat
Term_id = 32
Meta_key = cp_type
Meta_value = sale
Post-type = ad_listings
```

I have this sql:

```
$query = "
SELECT *
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
AND $wpdb->terms.term_id = '32'
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'cp_tips' 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'Pārdod' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'ad_listing'
";
```

But in this query i dont how to add terms:

Terms sql:

```
SELECT ID as PID FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'ad_cat'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 32
```

How to put all together?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
Not tested especially the taxonomy part, but itsShould work, or at least get you started.
The big advantage of wp_query is that you can use [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) on it

```
<?php
$query = array (
   'post_type' => 'ad_listing',
   'post_status' => 'publish' ,

   //que custom field
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'cp_tips',
            'value' => 'Pardod'
        )
    ),

    //term 32
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ad_cat',
            'field' => '32',
                    'terms' => array( 'action', 'commedy' )
        )
    )
);

$ad_list = new WP_Query($query);
```

Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). You need to use the part of the tax_query and meta_query, then you can grab the count from the property found_posts. Check the codex, it have examples and better explanation of all the options to use WP_Query